# SQL to update column in modified table

Tags: mysql

I am a reasonably competent SQL programmer but my skills are still pretty much in the domain of simple INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE statements with an occasional LIKE etc thrown in.  What I am currently trying to do is rather more complex.  Here is the scenario.

1. I have three tables.
2. Table 1, `*users*` identifies users via a User ID, **uid**.  Users can have one or more sub accounts
3. Table 2 `*accounts*` keeps a record of subaccounts for each user with, amongst other things the columns **uid** and **sid** where **uid** is the one defined in the `*users*` table.
4. Table 3, `*data*` is currently storing some data, in a **data** column that is being associated with a particular subaccount, **sid**.

The thing I have just realized is that there is no particular reason to block users from using those data across subaccounts.  No problem - I can change my data subset search SQL to work with the **uid** instead.  However, given the frequency of such searches, it seems well worth while simply sticking in a **uid** column in `*data*`.

To do that I would need to write some smart SQL that would get uid,sid pairs from the `*accounts*` table and use that information to update the newly created uid column in the **data** table.  This I have to admit is beyond my knowledge of SQL.

I should mention that the system using these data is now in production and has several 100s of users so the option of just acting like they are not there is not available.  Not terribly relevant I think but I should mention that **uid** and **sid** are alphanumeric strinsg with both columns being indexed.

I would be most grateful to anyone here who might be able to help out with it.

Comment: I should mention that I could do this with a spot of PHP.  However, given that I need to make the changes in a live environment the right bit of SQL sounds like a better option - not to mention that I would like to improve my SQL skils anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql can do updates based on joins and based on reading of your schema here's what I'd do...

```
UPDATE accounts a, data d
set d.uid=a.uid
where a.sid=d.sid
and d.uid is NULL
```